# Can typescript class decorators be optional when creating an instance?

Tags: typescript, oop, decorator

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), the decorator pattern allows you to decorate an instance of a class with extra functionality, for example:

```
let ball = new BouncyBall(new Ball())
```

The `Ball` instance gets decorated with extra code from the `BouncyBall` class. I can still get a regular `Ball`:

```
let simpleOldBall = new Ball()
```

Now, when I look at the [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html) for *Class Decorators*, it seems that all `Ball` instances will automatically be decorated with the `bouncyBall` code:

```
@bouncyBall
class Ball {
}
```

How can I create balls *and* bouncy balls when using *Class Decorators* in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class decorator is declared before a class declaration and therefore applies to all instances of that class.

In your case you might want to look into [mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-mix-in-classes). This would allow something like this:

```
type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function Bouncy<T extends Constructor<{}>>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {
        bounce() {
            console.log('Bounce!');
        }
    }
}

class Ball {
}

const BouncyBall = Bouncy(Ball);

const bouncyBall = new BouncyBall();
bouncyBall.bounce();
```

Comment: Thanks! mixins didn't occur to me, will look into it! I have to say, it looks a bit messy doesn't it? (needing generics, an extra Constructor type, an `any` array, and extending a constructor....) 

I suppose I could still use the standard pattern from wikipedia as well, no reason that wouldn't work in Typescript 